# Jquery datepicker 2 months display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jquery-ui datepicker for displaying multiple months.

The popup displays these months 1 below the other, is there a way to have the following month displayed to the right instead?

Comment: Are you including the CSS file? The divs for the months should have float: left set.

Answer (score 21):

I'm working with this in datePicker right now :) So, well, according to jQuery dataPicker documentation:

`numberOfMonths`

```
Number, Array 
Default:1
```

Set how many months to show at once. The value can be a straight integer, or can be a two-element array to define the number of rows and columns to display. Code examples

Initialize a datepicker with the `numberOfMonths` option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 3] });
```

Get or set the numberOfMonths option, after init.

```
//getter
var numberOfMonths = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "numberOfMonths" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "numberOfMonths", [2, 3] );
```

So as fas as I tried if you write

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: 2 });
```

it appears 2 months, one by the side of the other, in a row, horizontally. And In the case you want to display them vertically, in a column you should write

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 1] });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple `jQuery Datepicker` with `multiple months display option`:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ibile4/1/edit)

Source below:

[Source](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/10/show-multiple-months-in-jquery-ui.html)