# JQuery DatePicker multiple months generation

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using jQuery DatePicker and I am trying to generate multiple months from an interval.

My code so far in html:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div id="datepicker">
</div>
```

In my js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

**EDIT**
I am generating multiple date pickers but they are all on one column, is it possible to make them near each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery datepicker 2 months display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217203/jquery-datepicker-2-months-display)

Comment: The problem is that no matter what I do, my datepickers are not next to each other, but ony on one column.